# Reverse bits Leetcode question solution not passing all tests

Tags: javascript, debugging

[This](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-bits/) is the question and this is my solution which is not getting accepted. What am I doing wrong?

```js
/**
 * @param {number} n - a positive integer
 * @return {number} - a positive integer
 */
var reverseBits = function(n) {
    let arrOne = [];
    let arrTwo = [];
    let num = 0;
    arrOne = n.toString(2).split("");
    let m = 0;
    for (let i = arrOne.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arrTwo.push(arrOne[i]);
    }
    console.log(arrTwo);
    for (let k = arrTwo.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (arrTwo[k] == 1) {
            num += (2**m);
        }
        m++;
    }
    return num;
};
```

Comment: If you're resorting to strings *and* arrays, you missed the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that...
have  a look to  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

```js
/**
 * @param {number} n - a positive integer
 * @return {number} - a positive integer
 */
const reverseBits = n =>
  {
  let bin = 1
    , res = 0
    ;
  for (let x of n.toString(2))
    {
    if (+x) res |= bin // or if (x==='1')  res += bin 
    bin <<= 1          // binary shift left
    }
  return res
  }

let val = 243
  , res = reverseBits(val)
  ;
console.log( val, val.toString(2), '--> ', res, res.toString(2) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```